# How Do I get objects near my object in BGE 2.78a using an oct tree?

Tags: python, game-engine

[My Attempt.](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1024445695555543185/1074478007084916806/Oct_Tree_Get_Close.blend)

How Do I get objects near my object in BGE 2.78a using an oct tree? I essentially want to get stuff in 3d space within so much distance of my own object without scanning the ENTIRE scene and without using the near sensor.

Comment: This Q&A site doesn't support Blender Game Engine which no longer has anything to do with Blender. It was seperated from Blender some while ago. Try asking at https://upbge.org/#/community.

Comment: This isn't UPBGE and the BGE still exists by default in older versions. as for not supporting the BGE there are literally hundreds of answered and unanswered questions on it on this site.

Comment: There may be hundreds of answers, but all of them will be from a long time ago before the game engine was forked from Blender version 2.8. There's a seperate section for it on Stack Exchange [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-engine) and I see you've now asked your question there.